# Retrieve and mark holidays on Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am taking in black out dates information from a client and need to mark them on a google calendar.

The client simply checks the holiday on the form and it needs to be highlighted as an off-day on their calendar.

Google Calendar Script doesn't seem to provide a method to request dates of public holidays. Is there any way of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to Fetch Public Holidays Using Calendar API in App Script**

1.Fetch your calendarId [here](https://gist.github.com/mattn/1438183) according to which country's public holidays you'd like to see.

2.Use the code provided by App Script docs on [fetching list of Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar#listing_events):

```
function listNext10Events() {
      var calendarId = 'en.indian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com'; //I'm fetching Indian public holidays
      var now = new Date();
      var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
        timeMin: now.toISOString(),
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime',
        maxResults: 10 //set number of holidays you'd like to see, 10 for now
      });
      if (events.items && events.items.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++) {
          var event = events.items[i];
          if (event.start.date) {
            // All-day event.
            var start = parseDate(event.start.date);
            Logger.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, start.toLocaleDateString());
          } else {
            var start = parseDate(event.start.dateTime);
            Logger.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, start.toLocaleString());
          }
        }
      } else {
        Logger.log('No events found.');
      }
  }



 function parseDate(string) {
      var parts = string.split('T');
      parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/-/g, '/');
      return new Date(parts.join(' '));
 }
```

3. To execute this successfully enable Calendar API in App Script and Google Developer Console.

[Enabling advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services):

To use an advanced Google service, follow these instructions:

a. In the script editor, select Resources > Advanced Google services....

b. In the dialog that appears, click the on/off switch next to the service you want to use.

c. At the bottom of the dialog, click the link for the Google Developers Console.

d. In the console, click into the filter box and type part of the name of the API (for example, "Calendar"), then click the name once you see it.

e. On the next screen, click Enable API.

*Save the project and Run*.

View Logs to check the public holidays.

Comment: I tried this method but I'm facing problems with getting Calendar  to work. When I enable the api, it says I should create credentials. I ignored it and tried anyway. But it isn't working.

Comment: which part in my answer are you stuck? i've got it perfectly working on my end

Comment: The part where we retrieve events using `var events = Calendar.Events.list(...`. I get the following error in the Execution transcript: `Execution failed: Access Not Configured. Calendar API has not been used in project 60727xxxxx8 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/calendar/overview?project=60727xxxxx8 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry`

Comment: go to google dev console and enable Calendar API, it's that easy :)

Comment: Yea I did but it's not working. Actually, when I open the developer's console it opens to my private gmail account and not my company account and it reads `You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page.` . When I switch to the company account I can't find the project in it. I tried enabling the api from the company account anyway but it still fails.

Comment: use company acct, go to dashboard, click Enable. Type Calendar in the search. Enable it